# Is their a point in running a realization (simulation) for more than 1 iteration?

Tags: sampling, simulation

Let's say I have a schedule of jobs assigned on workstation, and I create a distribution for each combination of job/workstation based on historical data. I can now 'realize' the duration of one schedule by sampling the duration of jobs from the fitted distributions, doing this, we realize the schedule for 1 iteration.

Would there be a point in realizing the schedules for more than one iteration? The goal would be to get a general overview of the length of a schedule, but if we run it for lets say 1000 (or an infinite) number of iterations the average total length would simply return to a sum of the average of the distributions we sample from.

The only reason I can think of that we an overview of the variance of a schedule, am I missing something here?

Comment: How are you doing your sampling? If you just resample the entire data set with the same number of observations and without replacement, you will wind up with the same data in a shuffled order.

Comment: I loop over the jobs in the schedule. For each job I sample a duration from the corresponding job/workstation distribution. I do this for all jobs to for 1 realization.